# How do I interpret two apostrophes in output

Tags: output-formatting, trigonometry, output

I am new with to the Wolfram language. Please can you tell me what `´´` means?

I got an output formula with

> ```
> cos´´
> ```

and

> ```
> sin´´
> ```

and only with one apostrophe `sin´` and `cos´` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `'` is the short form notation for taking a derivative. For example,

```
 Sin''[x]
```

gives

> ```
> -Sin[x]
> ```

which is the 2nd derivative of `Sin[x]`.

You can see how it is interpreted by Mathematica by inactivating the `Sin` function:

```
Inactivate[Sin''[x]]
```

[image: expression]

However, you probably shouldn't be seeing things like `sin''` and `cos''` in your output. It is likely you should change `sin` and `cos` in your input to `Sin` and `Cos`. All built-in function of the Wolfram language begin with upper-case letters, and the language is case-sensitive.